# Sin as a goal of man

Tags: church-history, history, heresy

1. God created Man.
2. Only difference between human and animal is possibiity of sin.
3. Hence God create man for only this purpose, commit sin. And from sin we  glorify God.

Are there exists in the past/present some heresy/movement with such views?

Comment: If there does, it is not a Christian movement. This question is nothing to do with Christianity.

Comment: There aren't many Christian heresies that deny the immortality of the soul, so I don't think you're going to find one

Comment: It would be difficult for such a heresy to gain believers, because statement 2 is visibly false. The primary difference between humans and animals is the ability of humans to understand at least a few things about God and to love, obey, and worship Him.

Comment: The question starts with a huge error: "Only difference between human and animal is possibiity of sin."

Answer (score 2):

When God created Adam and Eve they were without sin.  Although it is true that sin entered into the world because Adam and Eve disobeyed God, and that we are all sinners, God did not create man in order to sin. Indeed, after Adam and Eve sinned God provided the permanent solution to sin - Christ Jesus.

We are all sinners, and we continue to struggle with sin even after we are saved. We will never know a total absence of sin until we are with the Lord in glory:

> “When Christ appears, we shall be like him” (1 John 3:2).

There is no Christian denomination I know of that believes God created man to commit sin, and that by sinning, men glorify God. On the contrary, the Bible has this to say about sin:

> “If we claim to be without sin, we deceive ourselves and the truth is not in us” (1 John 1:8).

However, for all who come to saving faith in Christ Jesus, their lives are transformed:

> “No one who lives in [Christ] keeps on sinning. No one who continues to sin has either seen him or known him” (1 John 3:6)

> “We know that anyone born of God does not continue to sin; the One who was born of God keeps them safe, and the evil one cannot harm them” (1 John 5:18)

Here is the clue as to the origin of sin - "the evil one" who is a liar and the father of the lie.  Not God.

> “No one who is born of God will continue to sin, because God’s seed remains in them; they cannot go on sinning, because they have been born of God” (1 John 3:9).

A genuine Christian will not “deliberately, knowingly, and habitually” sin because that does not bring glory to God. There is no sin in God.  God can't even look upon sin.  God will always punish sin.

Christians are to walk in the light, not in the darkness (1 John 1:6–7); admit and confess sin (1 John 1:8); obey God’s Word (1 John 2:3–5); love God rather than the world (1 John 2:15); seek to “do what is right” (1 John 2:29); maintain a pure life (1 John 3:3). As a result, the believer sees a decreasing pattern of sin in his life (1 John 3:5–6; 5:18).

Throughout human existence there have been men who rejoice in evil and some who even claim there is no such thing as sin.  Such men have fallen for the lies of that original enemy of God, the one who walks in darkness.  They are not Christians.

Answer (score 0):

If it were not for sin there would never have been any possibility of the display of God's mercy.

God is not glorified by our sin, but he *is* glorified by forgiving our sins.  If there were no sin, it would not be possible to know the depths of God's love or have any idea that he is merciful.

> *For God has consigned all to disobedience, that he may have mercy on all.  Oh, the depth of the riches and wisdom and knowledge of God! How unsearchable are his judgments and how inscrutable his ways!* (Romans 11:32-33)

So, even though it is/was not man's purpose to ultimately bring glory to God when chose/chooses to sin, yet without our sin a huge aspect of God's character would remain forever hidden.  So it isn't wise to say our sins bring glory to God... God's mercy brings him glory.  But, nevertheless, our forgiven sins have been instrumental in bringing glory by God by enabling the display of God's grace.

And those whose sins remain unforgiven bring glory God by enabling the display of God's holy indignation and wrath.